# Remove the "-u" parameter when executing code remotely from PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I have set up a Remote Interpreter to a Server from PyCharm. The connection is working fine and i have also configured the Deployment from my local machine to this server.

The interpreter i configured is from Spark (/usr/bin/spark-submit). But, when i run my code, it outputs the following error:

`Error: Unrecognized option: -u`

Below is the command that is being sent to the remote server:

`ssh://user@MYHOST:22/usr/bin/spark-submit -u /home/user/pycharm/main.py`

I have tried with the Python Interpreter, using the Python from the remote server and it worked just fine. The problem is that spark-submit does not accept the option  **-u** but i cannot remove that option from PyCharm. Also, i've removed the PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 environment variable from the **Run Configurations** in PyCharm, but it did not work.

[image: 1] Field which i have removed the PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 option

Parameters Field in Run Configurations:
[image]

I have also searched the JetBrains forum, but didn't find anything that refers to this problem.

Comment: what does it say under parameters in run config?

Comment: I've updated my question with the print from Parameters in Run Configurations. Thanks!

Comment: I am not super familiar with spark, but I do not think this is a Pycharm issue. Maybe take a look at the interpreter you configured from spark and look for an optional parameter of some kind. The fact that it works with the python interpreter is a big tell.

Comment: When i used the Python interpreter directly from the Server (/usr/bin/python3.6) it shows the same **-u** option. The problem is, when you submit a spark application with spark-submit, the option **-u** does not exist. But it seems that PyCharm always send that option, doesn't matter the interpreter.

Comment: Unfortunately I cant really help then ://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/big-data-tools-spark-submit.html this details how to configure for spark, that's my best guess

Comment: Thank you very much friend @fthomson! I have followed the post and after installing the Big Data Tools plugin, it worked! I was not even close, since the Run Configuration should be directed to spark-submit. If you post as Answer, i will gladly mark as Solution and Upvote. Again, many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

the bug is reported in pycharm tracker, and here is the hacky workaround from the forums. Just create an executable wrapper around spark executable, that removes the `-u argument`.

```bash
#!/bin/sh

for arg do
  shift
  [ "$arg" = "-u" ] && continue
  set -- "$@" "$arg"
done

exec /usr/bin/spark-submit "$@" # unlike original comment from source, arg needs to be quoted to work properly.
```

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DS-3593/Support-spark-submit#focus=Comments-27-3000603.0-0

/Edit: It doesn't have to be spark executable. I had the same issue with python 3.9.5 on the remote, and I solved it creating the wrapper around it this way.